# Почему через функцию можно использовать изменяемую ссылку?

Tags: rust, ссылка

```
fn main() {   
    let mut n = 123;
    let m = &mut n;

    println!("n: {}", n);
    println!("&n: {}", &n);
    
    //*m = 332; // Ошибка!
    modify_ref333(&mut n); // почему же так нормально, 
    // несмотря, что предыдущая строка вызывает ошибку? 
    // ведь она делает ТОЖЕ САМОЕ!

    println!("n: {}", n);
    println!("&n: {}", &n);  
}

fn modify_ref333(m: &mut i32) {
    *m = 333; // ok
}
```

Если откомментировать `*m = 332;` в `main`, это вызовет ошибку

> error[E0502]: cannot borrow `n` as immutable because it is also
> borrowed as mutable

и это объясняется и, вроде бы, понятно. Но! Ведь функция `modify_ref333` делает тоже самое - использует изменяемую ссылку, присваивая значение по адресу. Получается цели (как у них написано в официальном учебнике)

> Users of an immutable reference don’t expect the value to suddenly change out from under them!

> У нас также не может быть изменяемой ссылки, пока у нас есть
> неизменяемая ссылка на то же значение. Пользователи неизменной ссылки
> не ожидают, что значение внезапно изменится!

не достигается! Так легко "обмануть" компилятор или, все же, есть разница?

---

PS А вот так, оказалось, работает:

```
fn main() {
    let mut n = 123;
    
    println!("n: {}", n);
    println!("&n: {}", &n);
    
    let m = &mut n;
    *m = 332;

    println!("n: {}", n);
    println!("&n: {}", &n);  
}
```

Кто-нибудь может подсказать лаконичное правило, как можно использовать мьютабильную ссылку, а как нет, не нашел в доках (вернее, то, что там написано, нарушается примером)

Comment: так все там написано - по умолчанию все немутабельное. И если хочется что то менять - нужно явно указать это. Собственно это у Вас и происходит. И да, мутабельность при присваивании "не наследуется".

Comment: @KoVadim `let mut m = &mut n;` что ли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Rust в один момент времени может использоваться только одна изменяемая ссылка на объект. Первый пример компилируется из-за того что ссылка не используется и компилятор просто её не учитывает при проверке. Как только вы пробуете как-то ссылкой воспользоватся, то он выдаёт ошибку.
Передача в функцию происходит успешно, поскольку ссылка `&n` уже вышли из области видимости.
Второй пример работает по той же причине. В один момент времени используется только одна ссылка. По видимому компилятор не учитывает ссылку после последнего её использования.
Ну и ещё один пример для демонстрации

```
fn main() {   
    let mut n = 123;
    

    println!("n: {}", n);
    println!("&n: {}", &n);
    
    let m = &mut n;
    n = 334; // cannot assign to `n` because it is borrowed
    *m = 332; 
    modify_ref333(&mut n); 

    println!("n: {}", n);
    println!("&n: {}", &n);  
}

fn modify_ref333(m: &mut i32) {
    *m = 333; // ok
}
```

Как только вы пытаетесь использовать переменную, когда на неё существует изменяемая ссылка - компилятор возвращает ошибку.